# Python json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) with Spaces in path name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am uploading a file to a REST API with a Python 3 script via the windows command line.  The filename is an argument passed in to the script.  Everything works fine unless there is a space in the path name.  i.e. `c:\temp\myFolder\1.jpg` works, but `c:\temp\my Folder\1.jpg` throws an error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The code up until the error is as follows:

```
def upload_photo(filename):
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    data = f.read()
    data_md5 = hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
    f.close()
    r = requests.put('https://upload.mysite.com/{}'.format(filename), data=data)
    response = json.loads(r.text)
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks for the help.

--Edit--
    Full traceback

```
c:\>python test.py "c:/temp/my folder/1.jpg" 

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 144, in <module>
print(test(sys.argv[1]))
File "test.py", line 132, in upload_photo
response = json.loads(r.text)
File "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\Default\Default\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Can you please show what exacly you type in on the command line? I presume you need to quote the filename, or escape the spaces in it.

Comment: Or, you need to encode the spaces in the URL before making the request.

Comment: c:\>python test.py "c:/temp/my folder/1.jpg"

Comment: Can you please include the full traceback of the error message?

Comment: added in main question

Comment: check the response you get, namely the status and the content. you probably get  404 with empty response or something like that. Does the server allow to put to encoded url "upload.mysite.com/c:/temp/my folder/1.jpg" at all?

Comment: You're right.  Status 200 with no spaces.  401 with spaces

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the link properly; escaping the invalid character(s). You can do that with `urllib`.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> filename = urllib.parse.quote('c:\temp\my Folder\1.jpg')
>>> 'https://upload.mysite.com/' + filename
'https://upload.mysite.com/c%3A%09emp%5Cmy%20Folder%01.jpg'
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I tried that and still get the same error

Comment: >>>from urllib.parse import quote, urlparse

>>>r = requests.put('https://upload.mysite.com/{}'.format(quote(filename)), headers=headers, data=data)


 raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)